# MySQL CONCAT() Returns Unreadable Text

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I'm having some problems with the `MySQL CONCAT()` function. I ran the following:

`SELECT CONCAT(now(),now())`

And this is what I got back:

```
323031342d30352d30352031343a33393a3535323031342d30352d30352031343a33393a3535
```

Not sure what exactly what is going on? Has anyone seen this before? This happens when concatenating anything (columns, strings, mysql functions like `now()`)

My server version is `5.1.63 - SUSE MySQL RPM`" and the client version is `libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.7-dev - 091210 - $Revision: 304625 $`

Comment: can u share the complete query ? since `concat(now(),now())` should return something as `2014-05-06 01:24:242014-05-06 01:24:24`

Comment: Here's my "actual" query: `SELECT SUBSTR(MD5(CONCAT(email,"Salt")),1,16) FROM traveler` Result: `62383062623533343465343964646130`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like a hexadecimal representation of printable ASCII characters:

```
hex: 32 30 31 34 2d 30 35 2d 30 35 20 31 34 3a 33 39 3a 35 35
char: 2  0  1  4  -  0  5  -  0  5     1  4  :  3   9 :  5  5
```

I can't explain why the client is displaying character data as hexadecimal; <strike>I'd investigate the possibility that there's a mismatch in character set encoding.</strike>

Possibly the MySQL client library is using latin1, but the application is using a different encoding; but we'd expect this would affect all character expressions, not just CONCAT() expressions.

Actually, it's more likely the client is displaying hexadecimal for binary strings, and the value returned from CONCAT() is being reported as a binary string.

Here is an excerpt from [MySQL 5.1 documentation for CONCAT() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_concat):

> Returns the string that results from concatenating the arguments. May
>   have one or more arguments. If all arguments are nonbinary strings,
>   the result is a nonbinary string. If the arguments include any binary
>   strings, the **result is a binary string**. A numeric argument is
>   converted to its equivalent binary string form; if you want to avoid
>   that, you can use an explicit type cast, as in this example:
>
> ```
> SELECT CONCAT(CAST(int_col AS CHAR), char_col);
> ```

So, the workaround might be to CAST the value of NOW() as character, either using a CAST or possibly using the DATE_FORMAT function, e.g.

```
CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'),DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s'))
```

Comment: In addition, using the UNHEX() function works too. Like `UNHEX(SUBSTR(MD5(CONCAT(email,'Salt')),1,16))`

Comment: @David Kryzaniak: Good point. The `UNHEX()` function will work on a string containing hexadecimal digits (as returned by the `MD5()` function e.g.)  But I don't think it will give the desired result for strings that contain values other than hex digits (i.e. I'd  expect `UNHEX(CONCAT(NOW(),NOW()))` to return `NULL`.)